# DHCP vs. Static IPs in an Static IP network with 40 clients and ~10 servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server, windows-server-2016

I am arguing with a colleague about DHCP. We are using static IPs at the moment and an inventory tool like [Lansweeper](https://www.lansweeper.com/) to have the overview of our network. Besides we maintain a list of our clients and servers.

If we would setup a new network I would definitely say, that you should use DHCP, because of the configuration work. But in our case every client has it's own IP and there is no adress conflict.

**So what would be the advantage to switch from Static IPs to DHCP?**

We are using Windows Server 2016 and the OS supports DHCP-Failover so I think it is ok to rely on that. I also mean that there is a small benefit for changing the dns very fast, but how often will you do that?

We will independently from the DHCP topic have to go to any of the clients and configure another thing (sneaker administration FTW!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make my work easy in maintaining network inventory, I will bind MAC address to an IP address. This always gives same IP address when a particular server/Desktop/Laptop comes online after some time or maintenance period. Here we can always keep Interface in DHCP mode to receive Static IP address.

This way we can maintain Static ranges of IP addresses which is again maintained by DHCP.

Hope this solution helps..!!